# Somehow reference the hash value using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Let's assume I have a page that uses the `location.hash` to store info for the page, most of my visitors use js so there's no problem. Is there a way to use CSS to link to a non-JS version (using `location.search` instead) with the same value?

Imagine:

```
<noscript>Use this page instead</noscript>
<textarea></textarea>
<input id="save" type="checkbox" value="save">
<input id="run" type="checkbox" value="run">
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready( function() { $('textarea').val( unescape(location.hash) ) } );
$('#save').click(function() { location.hash = escape($('textarea').val()) });
$('#run').click(function() { /* Mess around with the DOM */ });
```

I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
noscript:after {
    content: full url with hash with a ? instead of a #
}
```

I realize that if I used `location.search` I wouldn't have a problem but I want the page to be usable with people with JS even offline.

I tried background image URL but that ignores the current pagename. I need something in CSS that can access the current URL in it's entirety.

Comment: I can't imagine that that's possible.  You're blurring the lines between CSS and JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have access to the current page's URL in a stylesheet.

The furthest you could go is with CSS3's `:target` selector on an element that you can apply content styles to (definitely not `input`), and `attr(id)` to get the value of the ID if its ID is the same as the URL hash fragment. And a *hardcoded* string representing the page URL (it might work in an internal stylesheet with `<style>` tags...):

```
/*
If the hash is #save, select [id="save"]
and make its ::after content 'http://example.com/?' followed by its ID.
*/
:target::after { content: 'http://example.com/?' attr(id); }
```

You cannot use the `attr()` function to get the ID of one element and put it in another, by the way, which is why I said you can't use it on `input` elements.

Comment: Even then, I doubt most people using modern browsers are the same people who would turn JS off... and no version of IE older than 9 supports `:target` either.

Comment: That would mean I would need to know ahead of time, what the hash is. I'm looking for a way around that, as the user can set it to anything they feel like

Comment: If JS is disabled, there really isn't much you can do anyway.